# jquery validation in external file

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery and the validation plugin to validate form entry on the client side.

Instead of overloading the rendered HTML I thought it would be a good idea to keep the validation rules for different forms in separate files.  However when I try to do this I keep getting a firebug error that validate is an unknown function.

Here are the validation rules:

```
(function($){
signinval = function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#login').validate({
            debug: false,

            rules: {
                loginEmail: {required: true, email: true},
                loginPassword: required
            },
            messages: {
                loginEmail: {required:"Please supply your Firstname",email:"Please supply a valid email"},
                loginPassword: "Please enter your password"
            }
        });
    });
};
})(jquery);
```

I include Jquery and the validate plugin prior to including the call to function signinval() and I still get the error.

I have trawled the net looking for a solution but cannot seem to find anything.

Can anybody point me in the direction of how to achieve this please.

EDIT:

The order of the includes is:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/val_signin.js"></script>
```

FURTHER EDIT:

When the code was in the main html file itself it works fine.  The code was originally in a $(document).ready() block and it worked fine.  I converted it to the function above following another post I had seen previously.

Comment: Can you show the order of your js files included? (jquery/validate)

Comment: any other error in your console

Comment: in your browser console can you try `jQuery.fn.validate`

Comment: @Java_User - I have edited my original post to show the order in which the includes are rendered.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - No there are no other errors in firebug.  I have tried jQuery.fn.validate in console and it comes back as undefined but I don't understand why it would do that considering the file is included??

Comment: do you have different versions of jQuery in your page

Comment: Reading the edit which you made, is there any reason why you changed the dom ready code?

Comment: @ArunPJohny no it is only one include.  The stupid thing is I have brought the code back into the page just to test and stopped HTML5 validation and it is throwing the same error and yet the plugin  has been loaded, because firebug shows no errors.

Comment: @Java_User - ignorance rather than a real reason.  I saw a post somewhere that said about converting it to a function so gave it a try and then thought it was working but it actually was the HTML5 implementation that was working over and above Jquery.validate.

Comment: Okay.. May be that's the reason its not working. Ideally you can just revert the code and use `$(document).ready(function(){` instead.

Comment: @Java_User - I have brought the code back into the main html file and it is included in a DOM block and it still isn't working.  Has this got anything to do with the fact that the site is modular and is within PHP include files?

Comment: May be. Not sure about PHP though but can you try moving all the required js files into the main html where your js code resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK persistence paid off in the end.  Because I am using foundation by zurb for the design layout jquery needs to be included at the bottom.  Of course I had included it at the top as well and the validation plugin but of course with Jquery being included at the bottom as well, this was causing the error.

keeping jquery at the top and removing the inclusion from the bottom means that everything works ok and the external file is fine.

Thanks to @Java_User and @ArunPJohny for all your help.

Regards
Graham